# random permutation of lines of text

Tags: bash, text-processing, random

If I have a file with following content:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0132
0137
0138
0141
```

How can I get a random permutation of them in bash?

Answer (score 17):

`shuf` is the command you are looking for.

From `man shuf`,

> -n, --head-count=COUNT
>                 output at most COUNT lines

So, for example to get 4 random lines from the file, you could use the command as,

```
shuf -n 4 file
```

You could even use the below approach.

```
head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < file` + 1)) file | tail -1
```

Where, the final pipe to tail will specify the number of lines you need in the output.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line

Comment: I always thought I had to install `shuf`, but it is also part of coreutils %-)

Comment: On OSX this would be `gshuf`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with coreutils' `sort` with any of the following:

```
sort -R file
sort --random-sort file
sort --sort=random file
```

from `man sort`:

```
  -R, --random-sort
          sort by random hash of keys

   --sort=WORD
          sort according to WORD: general-numeric -g, human-numeric -h, month
          -M, numeric -n, random -R, version -V
```